# Mocha/Superagent: Unable to upload file

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, superagent

I am trying to write test to upload a file using Mocha/Superagent. When this API is hit by client, it works perfectly. When I run the test it fails with 500 response code. I just can not figure out what is the issue. Here is the code I am using.

```
var request = require('supertest')("http://localhost:8081");
var app = require('../app.js');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should();
var filePath = '/test/myFile.jpg';//Folder where the file is located

var customHeaders = {
    "authToken": "Whatever"
};

describe('POST /files/upload/', function() {    
    it('should upload a file', function(done) {
        request
            .post('/files/upload/')
            .set(customHeaders)
            .field('UserName', 'ABC')
            .attach('image', filePath)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(err);
                expect(res.body.fileId).to.be.above(0);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Does anyone have a working example of uploading file using Mocha and Superagent?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a problem quite similar to yours. Let me explain a little.

This part **filePath** might be the problem.

> var filePath = 'path/to/file.png'

even no luck after I changed it into

> var filePath = require('path/to/file.png')

**However,** from trying require(path), it gives me insight that so I can put the attachment like this below.

> .attach('htmlInputTagName', '/home/hary/Documents/web-dashboard/public/img/logo.png')

Let see if you get something in `req.files` and `req.body` in your server side.

Edit: 
I just realized my solution is dedicated to local server. If you want to run it at another server, my solution is invalid.